# The programme I write is called Clock. I CANNOT run the clock constantly with the certain main function given(JAVA)

Tags: java, clock

The original question is below:

> You are required to complete the code of the Clock.
> Please finish writing the code of the two classes, Display and Clock and then figure out the problem.
>
> Please include the following public functions in class of Clock:
>
> 1. public Clock(int hour,int minute,int second);  Initialize the time
> 2. public void tick(); Run the clock
> 3. public String toString(); Return a String in the form of "hh:mm:ss"
>
> Then write a class of Main which should be the same as the following Main function:
>
> ```java
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>    java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
>
>    Clock clock = new Clock(in.nextInt(), in.nextInt(), in.nextInt());
>    clock.tick();
>
>    System.out.println(clock);
>
>    in.close();
> }
> ```

Here is my code:

```java
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        Clock clock = new Clock(in.nextInt(), in.nextInt(), in.nextInt());
        clock.tick();

        System.out.println(clock);

        in.close();
    }
}
```

```java
class Display 
{
    int value = 0; // value represent the time
    int limit = 0; // limit represent the largest number in time
    
    public Display(int limit) 
    {
        this.limit = limit;        
    }
    
    public void increase() 
    {
        value++;                   
        if (value == limit) 
        {
            value = 0;               
        }
    }
    
    public int getValue() 
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

```java
class Clock  
{
    Display hour = new Display(24); // Assign the limit
    Display minute = new Display(60);
    Display second = new Display(60);
    
    public Clock(int x, int y, int z) { // Type in the original time
       hour.value = x;
       minute.value = y;
       second.value = z;
    }
    
    public void tick() { // Run the clock
        second.increase();
        if (second.value == 0) {
            minute.increase();
            if (minute.value == 0) {
                hour.increase();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "%02d:%02d:%02d\n", 
            hour.getValue(), 
            minute.getValue(),      
            second.getValue()
        );
    }
}
```

With the main function fixed, I find it impossible to run the clock constantly. The clock can just tick once and then stop. How to achieve the program.

I expect that the clock can run constantly after initializing the time.

Comment: I don't see a thread, I don't see a loop ... why exactly do you expect (parts of) your code to be executed more than once?

Comment: I would recommend looking up a tutorial about loops. If you want some code to repeat more than once understanding the concept of loops is important and stackoverflow is not the right place to learn such basic knowledge.

Comment: The instructions don't say anything about making it loop.

Comment: @001 no, they don't. They do command to: "figure out the problem."

Comment: You will find answers to your problem on StackOverflow. Please only post a question if there was nobody asking something similar before.

Comment: Sorry,I assume that I do not describe the question clearly.  Maybe the Main function is given and I CANNOT add any other statement to the component. So I wonder where to put the loop? If I put an infinite loop in the function tick(), the main function can never implenment the statement "System.out.println(clock)"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some kind of loop in your main function. Maybe have a look at this source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-java/

But make sure you don't build an infinite loop. You should add some kind of termination. Hope this helps!

Comment: never just put a link as an answer. It becomes pointless once the link is removed

Comment: So maybe the expected programme can run constantly until I break the loop. So actually I need a infinite loop and I can see the numbers appearing fast on my screen. However,if I bulid an inifite loop in the function tick(), the statement "System.out.println()…" can never be implemented

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).